# Linux SFTP MGET * then Delete after transfer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp

I am running SFTP in Linux Ubuntu Server.

After connecting i run the command `mget*`

this downloads everything in the folder every time.
I want to either delete or rename the files so i don't re-download the same files again and again.

is there some sort of command within mget to delete after successful download?
I think i have seen it before but i cant find it now.

is there perhaps a conad similar to "`for FILE`"... that will work over SFTP?

Comment: Check this answer, no need to delete files and you better off keeping and archive http://serverfault.com/a/579125/149274

Comment: Maybe you should look into `rsync`...

Comment: I looked into this. it seems like a great aplication however it does not work for me since i dont have access to the host machine to install it.

Answer (score 0):

OK. i found a better way that works great and accomplishes my goal.

i wanted to only download files once so i changed my code to use LFTP instead of SFTP

and i used `mirror --newer-than=now-2hours` that downloads only files form within 2 hours and does not re-download if i have already.